# Perl 64 bit hex function

Tags: perl

I would like to read in 64 bit hexadecimal numbers and do math with them using Perl.

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
> perl -e 'use integer; printf("%x\n", hex("0xffffffffffff")<<2)'
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at -e line 1.
fffffffc
```

Comment: It works for me on a 64-bit CPU, but not on a 32-bit CPU.

Comment: always enable warnings, even on oneliners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine on my 64-bit system.

Try `use bignum` instead of `use integer`.

Comment: bignum prevents the error, but outputs the incorrect value on my 32-bit system.

Comment: I think the version of Perl on my system doesn't have 64bit support. Good to know that it is supposed to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Flimzy: `use bignum` outputs the right value on my 64-bit system.  Perhaps a bug in your Perl?  I do not actually have a 32-bit system anymore...

Comment: It does the right thing on my 64-bit system, too--but so does `use integer`. But on my 32-bit system bignum no longer errors out, but it produces the wrong output.

Comment: @Flimzy: That is what I am saying. If `use bignum` gives the wrong answer, that sounds like a bug in your Perl.  If it is a current Perl, it might be worth reporting...  "Wrong answer" is a very bad failure mode.

Comment: I think it's just a limit of printf's 32-bitedness.  If I just do a straight print, both systems produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something about your platform/OS isn't fully 64-bit.  Try Math::BigInt to avoid any trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use bignum, I prefer to selectively use Math::BigInt:

```
perl -wle'use Math::BigInt;  $number = Math::BigInt->new("0xffffffffffff"); $number += 67; print $number->as_hex()'
```